# Extending a Dojo custom build without profile definition?

Tags: javascript, dojo, profile, custom-build

In order to become acquainted with a poorly documented Dojo/JS project, I need to extend its current Dojo custom build by some more modules.

I have done it a several times for my own projects, checking-in the `*.-profile` file into version control every time, so that I can reuse it later for future builds from the Dojo sources.

This time I don't have a `*.-profile` file to review the app's module dependencies and extend them by my own ones. I know the existing Dojo environment is a custom build, but I don't know its dependencies and with which modules it was build, furthermore there are no `dojo.require` calls in its `index.php`.

What are my options to make an extended custom build based on the present custom build with all of its dependent modules?